# How to get rid of the red border when a DataGrid cell is invalid?

Tags: wpf

How do I do this? I want to get rid of that annoying red border that shows on each invalid datagrid cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ValidatesOnDataErrors and ValidatesOnExpcetions to False for your binding of your cell.
In case you want your validations, then you have to override the Validation Template for your control. Please refer to my answer here -
[Validation Error Style in WPF, similar to Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434245/validation-error-style-in-wpf-similar-to-silverlight/7435742#7435742)

Comment: I want it to validate the data. BUT I want to change the default red border style.

Comment: Not only is the redline annoying, but it gets applied to all the DataGridTemplateColumns even if they are NOT invalid, just because WPF calls for them GetError(null) instead of GetError( name of bound property).

Answer (score 9):

You can just add this line to your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue but in my case I wasn't using `IDataError` or `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. I'm using a custom `ValidationRule` and styles to handle my validation logic and presentation. I was already using the DataGrid `RowStyle` to display a custom style for the row that has errors so I thought it would be easy to do something similar with the DataGridCell.

Things to note:

1. You can't just define a style and set the `DataGrid.CellStyle`. Instead you have to use the `ElementStyle` and/or the `EditingElementStyle`.
2. The style `TargetType` has to match the DataGridColumn type that the cell is using. So for a DataGridComboBoxColumn the `TargetType` should be `ComboBox`

DataGrid Column XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Column1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Column1Path}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Column1DisplayPath"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource DGComboColValidationStyle}"
    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DGComboColValidationStyle}">

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedItemBinding>
        <Binding Path="Column1Path" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validation:CustomValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedItemBinding>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Style Definitions

```
<Style x:Key="DGComboColValidationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                            BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=adorner1, Path=DataContext[0].ErrorContent.ValidationType, Converter={StaticResource ValidationTypeColorConverter}}" 
                            CornerRadius="3">
                    </Border>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adorner1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DGTextColValidationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                            BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=adorner2, Path=DataContext[0].ErrorContent.ValidationType, Converter={StaticResource ValidationTypeColorConverter}}" 
                            CornerRadius="3">
                    </Border>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adorner2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DGRowValidationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="DGRowValidationTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5"
                        Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent.ValidationType, Converter={StaticResource ValidationTypeColorConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4,0,0,0"
                        Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="!"
                        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent.ValidationMessage}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent.ValidationType, Converter={StaticResource ValidationTypeColorConverter}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DGCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent.ValidationMessage}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d2d6513-7bca-4359-a12b-46da3c380b0a/wpf-4-datagrid-editingelementstyle-and-validationerrortemplate-adorner-layer?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks, seems overwriting TextBlock's peroperty "Validation.ErrorTemplate" do the trick. I wasn't aware the control has a template for errors.

Answer (score 2):

I hated the red border because it was put in the adorner and adorners sit on top of the window, meaning that if your element is partially/fully hidden by another element (like it is in a grid) the full adorner still shows :(

That didn't mean I didn't want some customization though, so I can still highlight my items in pink, or change their foreground and have the DataGridCell correctly clip everything off. You can do this by using a style trigger.

Hope this helps!

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="TextBlockErrorStyle">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <!-- Just the adorned element means NO RED BORDER -->
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="controlWithError" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Description" MinWidth="150">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextBlockErrorStyle}"
                        />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this as well 
[How to: Implement Validation with the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)