# Get rid of the textbox validation border

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

How to get rid of the red border around textbox automatically used for validation purposes?

Comment: what is your xaml of this textbox? Are you using any bindings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the ValidatesOnDataErrors and ValidatesOnExceptions to False for your binding of your textbox. In case you want your validations, then you have to ovveride the Validation Template for your control. Please refer to my answer here-
[How to get rid of the red border when a DataGrid cell is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677791/how-to-get-rid-of-the-red-border-when-a-datagrid-cell-is-invalid/7678073#7678073)

Comment: Just for the copy & pasters like me: "ValidatesOnExpcetions" contains a typo.

Answer (score 16):

Easiest way to do this:

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the very same answer is provided in the thread that Rohit references to.