# Custom Validation Template does not work for datagrid - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, templates, datagrid

I'm trying to add a custom validation template to my datagrid text column but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437765/3853836) template I found here. It works when I use it on a control that is not part of my datagrid, but doesn't work for my datagrid. The datagrid column is binded to a Observable Collection of objects, and the setter of the object properties throws an exception if the input is not valid.

Also, if I do not use any validation.ErrorTemplate, I do not get the red border when a validation error occurs, I just get a red exclamation ("!") on the row. And if I ignore that and click ok on my window it binds the cell with the validation error back to my collection as null, how can I avoid doing that? I tried e.Cancel = true in the RowEditEnding event, but that stops the whole validation process too.

Here's my xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.Column="0"
                              Margin="5"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              CanUserAddRows="True"
                              CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding _employeeList}"
                              RowEditEnding="OnRowEdit">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                                Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                                Header="Name" />

                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="130"
                                                Binding="{Binding ID,
                                                                  ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                                                                  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                                                Header="ID"
                                                Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplateSilverlightStyle}" />

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```