# Don't show Validation.ErrorTemplate of TextBox

Tags: wpf, styles

I add theme for application.

I set style for textbox, and set Validation.ErrorTemplate for it.

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxValidationToolTipTemplate}"
```

in validation template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxValidationToolTipTemplate">
  <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform x:Name="xform" X="-25" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Border Background="StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplateShadowBrush}" />
    <Border Background="StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplateShadowBrush}" />
    <Border Background="StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplateShadowBrush}" />
    <Border Background="StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplateShadowBrush}" />
    <Border Background="StaticResource ValidationErrorElement}" />
    <Border>
      <TextBlock Forground="{StaticResource LightBrush}" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" UseLayoutRounding="false" />
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When i remove Validation.ErrorTemplate of TextBox style, it show default validation. But when i use template don't show validation.

**EDIT**

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437765/970404) for set Validation.ErrorTemplate

Answer (score 1):

here is a somethings that in my opinion can help you; **TRY** to use the AdornedElementPlaceholder in your ControlTemplate, it helped me before. Here is the my ControlTemplate example (a tooltip will display the error).

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3 0 0 0">
                            <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=AdornedElementPlaceholder, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
                            <Ellipse Width="3" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 2 0 0" Fill="White"/>
                            <Ellipse Width="2" Height="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 2" Fill="White"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="AdornedElementPlaceholder"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Regards,

Comment: @ar.gorgin error will be displayed by tooltip when your is over the first Ellipse object (the red circle).