# Validation in WPF MVVM with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, validation, mvvm

I'm writing a WPF MVVM Light app using Visual Studio 2015. The data has been brought in using Entity Framework 6, using database-first to generate the models. In my MainViewModel.cs file, I'd like to validate the data before doing a `SaveChanges()`.

The examples I've seen talk about adding annotations to models (for example, [this](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2013/7/13/utilizing-inotifydataerrorinfo-in-wpf-mvvm-app)); however, I'm using auto-generated Entity Framework models. And my ViewModels reference `ObservableCollection<Employee>` objects -- nothing references fields directly, so that I can put annotations on them.

Here is the `SearchResults` property, which holds the results returned from EF:

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> _searchResults;
public ObservableCollection<Employee> SearchResults
{
    get { return _searchResults; }
    set
    {
        if (_searchResults == value) return;

        _searchResults = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SearchResults");
    }
}
```

The `SearchResults` gets populated after a search and are bound to a DataGrid:

```
var query = Context.Employees.AsQueryable();

// Build query here...

SearchResults = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(query.ToList());
```

The user clicks a row on the DataGrid and we show the details for them to update. They can then hit the Save button. But we want to validate the fields in each `Employee` before performing `Context.SaveChanges()`.

Here's the pertinent area of the partial class `Employee`, auto-generated by Entity Framework:

```
public int employeeID { get; set; }
public int securityID { get; set; }
public string firstName { get; set; }
public string middleName { get; set; }
public string lastName { get; set; }
public string suffix { get; set; }
public string job { get; set; }
public string organizationalUnit { get; set; }
public string costCenter { get; set; }
public string notes { get; set; }
public System.DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
```

For example, the `securityID` must not be blank and it must be an `int`, while `firstName` and `lastName` are required, etc. How do you accomplish this validation and show errors to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume when you show user the details you are using `TextBox`es (You can apply the same solution for other controls).

Instead of validating data after the user changes the properties of `Employee`, just validate beforehand and don't even change the properties if they are invalid.

You can do this easily with `ValidationRule` class. For example:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" Name="ListBoxEmployees">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding ElementName="ListBoxEmployees" Path="SelectedItem.Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <stackOverflow:NotEmptyStringValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

and the validation rule:

```
public class NotEmptyStringValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Field cannot be empty.");
        }

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

Also you can disable the Save button when any of the validation rules fail.

Comment: Thanks, @qqww2. How would I show the error message next to the field that's being validated?

Comment: Look for `Validation.ErrorTemplate`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434245/validation-error-style-in-wpf-similar-to-silverlight) is a good looking one.