# How can change the position of the mouse which triggers a WPF tool tip?

Tags: .net, wpf

I want the tool tip to only show up when the mouse hovers over the top right hand corner of the control it is applied to, say a text box for example. What I am trying to do is do get a result similar to this [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434245/validation-error-style-in-wpf-similar-to-silverlight/7437765#7437765) using a tool tip instead of an adorner so the message can appear outside that window and doesn't get cut off when the control it is applied to is near the edge of the window. If I can't customize a tool tip to do this, can I create some other kind of element which can appear outside the window?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following properties on the Popup: `PlacementTarget` - you set this to be your control - and `Placement` - you set this to `Right` .

Note that the popup will automatically change its location if that goes off screen.